# Pagination in UITableView once it in the bottom

Tags: swift, api, uitableview

I am trying to make pagination for my tableView

I added the condition for checking the last cell in indexPath, but it does not work in the following code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == articles?.articles.count ?? 2 - 1 {
        pageNumber += 1
       

        catPass = PassUrl(categoryName: titleName ?? "", id: sourceId, searchText: labelText, pageInt: pageNumber)

        APICall.shared.fetchData(category: catPass) { (response) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.articles = response
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }
   
  
}
```

When I scroll down to the last cell, it does not load more.

How this func could be corrected?

Comment: Try this ``` if (indexPath.row >= articles?.articles.count ?? 2) - 1 {```

Comment: @RajaKishan still the same(

Comment: What is the current count ?

Comment: @RajaKishan it is 1


here is the full code link, i think it is better there to understand what I am to do

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/f5K

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will help you getting it done:

```
let lastItem = (articles?.articles.count ?? 2) -1 
            if lastItem == indexPath.row {
                if pageNumber < 100{ //in case you have a limit
                    pageNumber += 1
                     catPass = PassUrl(categoryName: titleName ?? "", id: sourceId, searchText: labelText, pageInt: pageNumber)

          APICall.shared.fetchData(category: catPass) { (response) in
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.articles = response
              self.myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
                }
```

Comment: it updates "limit" everytime when I scroll my tablview.
And instead of APIcall() above I changed to :

catPass = PassUrl(categoryName: titleName ?? "", id: sourceId, searchText: labelText, pageInt: pageNumber)
                
                APICall.shared.fetchData(category: catPass) { (response) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.articles = response
                        self.myTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

Comment: change limit with pagenumber

Comment: I changed to pageNumber 

can you take a look for this https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/f5M

Comment: try this ``` let lastItem = (articles.count ?? 2) -1 ```

Comment: add the code to github to be able to download it

Comment: I can't share with github, i think that the problem somewhere in the tableview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234619/discussion-between-menaim-and-bakhtovar-umarov).